# What is the cause for the failure: "jarsigner: attempt to rename {file} to {file}.org failed" when signing jars with ant?

Tags: java, ant, jarsigner

I am getting the error:

> [signjar] jarsigner: attempt to rename
>   C:\workspace\line_editor\lib\icon.jar
>   to
>   C:\workspace\line_editor\lib\icon.jar.orig
>   failed

when attempting to self sign a set of jars with ant inside Eclipse. The ant build has worked fine in this project and similar code in other projects.  I made some small changes to code and tried to rebuild and keep getting this error.

Here is the related ant target:

```
<target name="sign" depends="jar" description="Signs Jars">

        <genkey keystore="myKeystore1" alias="something" storepass="somethingpass" 
          dname="CN=Classification, OU=NAPA, O=GPC, C=US"/> 


        <signjar keystore="myKeystore1" alias="something" storepass="somethingpass">
            <fileset file="${web.dir}/${jar.name}" />
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>  
        </signjar>
    </target>
```

I deleted the project and pulled it down again from our repository.  So it has the same default project settings as other projects that this part does not fail.  I looked at the .jar in question and it was not read-only.  I changed the name and the next alphabetical .jar file also failed.  There is no program running that is accessing the .jars in this folder.

Any suggestions as to cause?

Comment: Updated question with more specific error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility is that the jar - which is in a 'lib' directory - is on a classpath in use during your build.  Is `${lib.dir}` included on a classpath used in the buildfile?

You could create a separate directory to deposit signed jars to, and specify that to the 'signjar' task using the [destdir](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) attribute.

Comment: Yes I was also using it in the classpath higher in the build.  I used your suggestion worked perfectly. Not sure why I have not had the problem in the past.

Comment: I noticed that this happened only when Netbeans (8.1, yes this is still an issue) was open and the jar was in its classpath. I had to remove the jar from the classpath AND restart netbeans to run jarsigner on it (or close netbeans and run it from another IDE).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try renaming the jar file yourself. If it can't be renamed, you can usually figure out which application has a file lock on it. Most likely some instance of java. Quit all java-based apps and try again. (Use task manager to make sure your java/javaw are not running.) After that, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks for `jarsigner.exe` in the home directory of the *JRE* chosen for the project.  If the JRE is just a JRE (not a JDK) this program will not be present.

Try setting a project-specific JRE and make sure it is actually a JDK.

Comment: As far as I can tell the JRE chosen is a JDK.  Other projects work fine doing the same operation, I will keep digging into the project specific settings to see if I can find a difference.

Comment: I was able to find a more specific error message and updated my question.  Looks like the jarsigner is having trouble renaming the .jar file.